# AWS-EKS deployed pod is exposed with type service Node Port is not accessible over nodePort IP and exposed port

Tags: amazon-eks

### I've created k8s cluster on AWS using EKS with Terraform followed this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/what-is-eks.html .

*I have one worker node*.`Note: Everything is in Private Subnets`

### Just running node.js hello-world container

### *Code for pod definition*

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nodehelloworld.example.com
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  containers:
  - name: k8s-demo
    image: wardviaene/k8s-demo
    ports:
    - name: nodejs-port
      containerPort: 3000
```

### *Code for service definition*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 31001
    nodePort: 31001
    targetPort: nodejs-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: helloworld
  type: NodePort
```

`kubectl get pods` shows that my pod is up and running

```
nodehelloworld.example.com   1/1       Running   0          17h
```

`kubectl get svc` shows that my service is also created

```
helloworld-service   NodePort    172.20.146.235   <none>        31001:31001/TCP   16h
```

`kubectl describe svc helloworld-service` it has correct *end-point* and correct *selector*

### So here is the problem

When I hit NodeIP:exposed port(which is 31001) I'm getting `This site can’t be reached`

then I used `kubeclt port-forward podname 3000:3000`

I can hit with `curl -v localhost:3000` is reachable

I checked my security group inbound rule  is 0-65535 from my CIDR block.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I have the exact scenario i can access internally but not from outside as the worker is in private subset. I guess I have to somehow link up with a load balancer. have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed..
On AWS EKS nodeports are not working as on Pure Kubernetes. 
when you exposing

```
  - port: 31001
    targetPort: nodejs-port
    protocol: TCP
```

31001 that's the clusterIP port will get exposed.

in order to get nodePort you must describe your service and look for NodePort is description that was exposed

Comment: I supose that when you say 31001 is the clusterIP port that will get exposed but internally, what about if you want to access this service externally and the workers are all private.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect from outside the cluster then in the security group for worker nodes you will have to add a custom TCP entry for enabling inbound traffic on port 31001.
[image: Add an entry to Inbound rules in your worker node security group]

If that does not work then make sure you are able to connect to the Node through that IP. I usually connect using a VPN client.

Comment: in the description  i said that my inbound for security in worker nodes is 0-65535

Comment: If the inbound rule for port 0-65535 has source mentioned as the security group for worker nodes then you would be able to connect if you are trying to connect from one of the worker nodes. If you are trying to connect from a machine which is not the worker node then you will have to mention the inbound rule as mentioned earlier by me. I can clarify more if you could share the inbound rules screenshot.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I have 2 custom tcp rules with  0-6553 from **my_range** in node_workers_sg too. This should work.. supposed to work.. also is possible that security groups will override each other? on my worker node I have 2 sg's attached currently

Comment: From where are you trying to hit NodeIP:exposed port?

Comment: From my laptop while I’m on VPN

Comment: Ahaa..so you need to add those entries because you are basically trying to access your worker nodes from a machine that is outside the vpc..

Comment: If i am on VPN then those entries are whitelisted already within security group.. If i am out of vpn then I can't hit anything within that VPC

Comment: @AnshulPrakash I have the same scenario, workers in private subnet, I want to access the service from outside the vpc, eg my machine at work network or my-house network, how can I achieve this?